# Chess challenge #8: British knockout championship

Tags: tactics, problems, check, perpetual

The British Knockout championship is taking place now as a warm-up to the London Chess Classic that starts this Friday. There have been very interesting games (especially the ones played by Nicholas Pert) like this one between Jonathan Rowson and Gawain Jones.

```
[fen "5rk1/4R3/1pQp4/3Pp3/4B1pp/4q1P1/PP3rPK/3R4 w - - 0 1"]
```

Gawain had a huge advantage but has just played ...h4 letting it slip away. Rowson has one chance to avoid losing the game. **What should he play?**

Comment: Rg7+ follows by never ending check with the White's queen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tags seem to give a big hint . . .

> 1 Rg7+! Kxg7 (Kh8 can't be better, since White can at least repeat with 2 Rh7+ Kg8 3 Rg7+)
>  2 Qd7+ Rf1-f7 (Rf8-f7 3 Qxg4+ and perpetual check since White has access also to c8; K-moves get mated: Kf6? 3 Qe6+ and 4 Qg6, or Kh6/g8/h8? 3 Qh7+)
>  3 Qxg4+ Kh8 4 Qxh4+ Kg8 and White can either take the perpetual starting 5 Qg4+ (checks from h3/g4/e6/c8) or go for more with 5 Rf1!?

Answer (score 4):

> `1. Rg7+!!`
>  if `1 .. Kh8 2. Rh7+ Kg8 3. Rg7+  etc`
> if `1 .. Kxg7 2. Qd7+` followed by perpetual check from the white queen on the white squares (`e6` & `g4`).